# Typescript: Find Type Group

Tags: typescript, types, ngrx

I have a a few types:

```
type A = A1 | A2 | A3;

type B = B1 | B2 | B3;

type AnyType = A | B;
```

All the types (`A1`, `A2`, `A3`, `B1`, `B2`, `B3`) are classes.

There's also a function which receives an `AnyType` called `action`:

```
function myReducerFunction(action: AnyType) {
  // Does action belong to A or B here?
}
```

I'm building a reducer with NgRx and I'd like to split the switch statement into more manageable blocks. Hence, depending on whether action is any of `A` or any of `B` I'd return whatever a "subreducer" returns, instead of handling it all in one big function.

So, how can I know if `something` is an `A` or a `B` inside that function?

Would it make more sense to use interfaces instead of types? If it would, could it be done with types anyway, and how?

Comment: Are they classes ? Or type aliases. because it is not clear from your code. Also if `A*` are classes do they share a base class ? same for `B*` ?\

Comment: They are unrelated classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typescript's types don't exist during runtime, so you'll need to use plain JS to decide what type your action is.

Since `A1-3` and `B1-3` are classes, this can easily be done with `instanceof`.
Combined with a [type predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#using-type-predicates) you can build something like:

```js
function isTypeA(val: AnyType): val is A {
  return [A1, A2, A3].some(clazz => val instanceof clazz);

}

function isTypeB(val: AnyType): val is B {
  return [B1, B2, B3].some(clazz => val instanceof clazz);
}

function myReducerFunction(action: AnyType) {
  if (isTypeA(action)) {
    // TS will now assume action is of type A.
  } else {
    // TS will now assume action is of type B.
    // You might not even need `isTypeB` since TS will be smart enough to realize 
    // `action` can only be type B here.
  }
}
```

With type predicates, you'll be able to access properties exclusive to `A1-3` or `B1-3` without Typescript complaining!

Comment: That's exactly it. Thank you. Unrelated, perhaps, but would you know how to transform that array of classes `[A1, A2, A3]` to an union `A1 | A2 | A3` or viceversa? I need both, but I squirm at the thought of duplication.

Comment: Found the answer to that myself: `const _A = [A1.prototype, A2.prototype, A3.prototype] as const;` and then `type A = typeof _A[number];`

Comment: That's exactly it! Thanks for sharing so others can find it too :)

Answer (score 1):

If you were using pure "shapes" without class information, each shape would typically have a common member, e.g., `kind` and you would use that as an identifier.

```
  enum Kind {
      A1=1,A2,A3,B1,B2,B3
  }

  type A1 = {
      kind: typeof Kind.A1
      foo:number
  }
  type A2 = {
      kind: typeof Kind.A2
      bar:number
  }

function myReducerFunction(action: AnyType) {
  switch (action.kind){
      case Kind.A1: console.log(action.foo); break;
      case Kind.A2: console.log(action.bar); break;
  }   
}
```

Of course since you already wrote in classes you could also distinguish by using `instanceof`.  But beware `c instanceof C` also matches any class extending `C`.